# Mac OS X doesn't allow to name files starting with a dot. How do I name the .htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, filenames, osx-leopard

As mentioned in the title, Mac OS X doesn't allow me to name files starting with a dot ( . ).

> You can’t use a name that begins with a dot “.”, because these names are reserved for the system. Please choose another name.

But, I need an .htaccess file. Or, better, how do I use an htaccess file in Mac OS X without giving it a name starting with a dot?

I am running Mac OS 10.5.8 and [XAMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) 1.7.3.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

As of 2023, the content of this answer is obsolete, as it was originally written in 2011. Please refer to [the up-to-date answer below.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51788836/139010)

---

You can't do this with the Finder. Open [Terminal.app](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal.app) (`Applications -> Utilities -> Terminal`), and type:

```
> cd /path/to/directory/containing/htaccess
> mv current_file_name .htaccess
```

Example (do not take directory names or initial filename literally, of course):

[image: terminal screenshot]

Comment: Explorer let's you do it by adding a dot at the end of the name, e.g. `.aws.` saves as  `.aws`

Comment: @mtman are you referring to Windows Explorer? That's not so helpful on a Mac `;-)`

Comment: Of course. Your mention about Explorer is incorrect.

Comment: Oh - I see. Thanks! I didn't read my own answer carefully enough to remember that I'd mentioned Windows Explorer 7+ years ago.

Comment: It's easier if you just do `command`+`shift`+`.` to toggle hidden files visibility. Once hidden files are visible you can rename them starting with a dot. No need for terminal (see my answer below).

Answer (score 90):

## Finder-only Solution. No Terminal Needed

You need to be able to see invisible files first.

In finder press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> –command + shift + dot– to toggle hidden files visibility.

Then just go to the folder where the file is and you'll see it there. You can now rename the file to start with a `.` if you want.

To create a new file you'll need the terminal. Do `touch .htaccess` once the terminal is at the right folder.

Comment: This is the best option imho, because there's no need to fiddle with Terminal.

Comment: You're the best :)

Comment: best option, no need to change any settings on the Mac

Comment: with some (European) mac keyboards, to toggle hidden files' visibility, you need to press: cmd + shift + fn + dot (extra key to press simultaneously = fn)

Comment: Best solution for this question from my perspective. Thanks @daniel Reina

Comment: it looks like this stopped working as of macos 14.3.1. I still get the "cannot name files with . ..." message.

Answer (score 62):

You can create files that begin with a "." if you can view hidden files.

Enter the following commands to show hidden files:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool YES
killall Finder
```

When you're done enter these commands to hide them again:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool NO
killall Finder
```

Comment: It's easier if you just do `command`+`shift`+`.` to toggle hidden files visibility

Comment: @DanielReina awesome!

Comment: @DanielReina your comment should have been the accepted answer

Comment: @RaheelSadiq Thanks! Make sure you upvote it (it's a bit down below) so more people can find it

Comment: If you need a quickly and temporary solution, on Finder, you may use "cmd + shift + .  "  ( command plus shift plus dot ) to display or not hidden files

Answer (score 11):

Use the terminal instead of Finder to rename it. Try `mv`.

Answer (score 5):

You can add an alias in your startup script file to make the command shorter. Usually this is .bashrc, .bash_login or .profile file in your home directory.

```
alias ondot='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool YES; killall Finder'
alias ofdot='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool NO; killall Finder'
```

Now you can just type `ondot` to show hidden files. and `ofdot` for hiding hidden files

Comment: Very cool. Implemented this on El Capitan using the file called `.bash_profile` in my user directory. Also ran into this [article with a bunch of other potential uses of the .bash_profile file](https://natelandau.com/my-mac-osx-bash_profile/).

Answer (score 3):

This works so far as it goes. But TextEdit automatically added .txt to the end of the filename so I ended up with .htaccess.txt

And files with names starting with . don't show up in folders in Finder. You only see it if you go back into Terminal and use ls -a. And if it can't be seen then it can't be uploaded to an online webserver.

Using Fetch as my FTP client, I found it has a function which enables me to create a simple text file directly on the server. This worked to create .htaccess where I really needed it.

Comment: If you are needing to edit a text file, use a text editor and not a word processor. `emacs`, `vim`, and `nano` are accessible via the command line all come pre-installed on macOS. If you want an editor with a GUI, Sublime Text is a popular choice. [citation needed]

Answer (score 2):

Since .htaccess files will not be viewable once you change the name with Terminal (without some annoying searching) it is simpler to just drag an empty text file into the directory of choice using FTP and then rename away.  Both filename and extensions can be change/removed once inside FTP.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with FTP.

Comment: It’s an htaccess file, which means OP is working with servers. FTP is a valid solution to working with servers and handling files. SO doesn’t demand word parity between question and answer it demands relevance, which I provided.

Answer (score 2):

Use Terminal.

1. Open Terminal.
2. Change Directory to source folder where you want to create the file

   - `cd Desktop`
3. Create the file using `touch`

   - `touch .htaccess`
4. Open the file in any text editor

   - `atom .htaccess`