# upload .well-known/assetlinks.json to Firebase Hosting on Mac

Tags: firebase-hosting, firebase-dynamic-links

I am setting up a Firebase Dynamic Links using App Links for a website that is also hosted in Firebase Hosting. I need to upload a `.well-known/assetlinks.json` to my Firebase Hosting website.

I am working on Mac, and if I try to create the `.well-known` folder on my Mac's drive it says: [image]

This makes it for me impossible to create, and then of course also upload the `assetlinks.json` (using the Firebase CLI which is the only tool that allows you to publish files to Firebase Hosting).

How can I install the required .well-known/assetlinks.json on my Firebase Hosting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mac OS X doesn't allow to name files starting with a dot. How do I name the .htaccess file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891365/mac-os-x-doesnt-allow-to-name-files-starting-with-a-dot-how-do-i-name-the-hta)

Comment: Make the folder with the terminal instead of finder.

Answer (score 3):

I found the following work-around:

(1) Create a `well-known/assetlinks.json` locally => notice its without the `.` at the beginning which made it impossible on my Mac to create this folder originally

(2) Update the `firebase.json` file to add a rewrite rule :

```
"rewrites": [
          ...
          {
            "source": "/.well-known/assetlinks.json",
            "destination": "/well-known/assetlinks.json"
          },
          ...
        ],
```

(3) Publish to firebase hosting

Its not an ideal solution, but it works...

Comment: Note that you could also create a folder with a "." at the beginning if you do it from the terminal using "mkdir .well-known". The "." at the beginning makes the folder hidden by default. It gets listed only if you ask for all hidden files to be shown or use "ls -a"

Comment: I am using react to host site on firebase , I simply created a well-known folder manually with assets.json file and used firebase deploy hosting target:mysitename, it worked.

Comment: rewrite path not working

Comment: Works in validator as well ! Thank you for this nice workaround  https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator

Comment: The issue is actually "**/.*",
Specify wich files you want to ignore and leave well-known